# Django queryset traversal (without evaluation)

Tags: python, django, django-models

lets say you have the following model:

```
class Connect:
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

in order to connect models `A` and `B` (this table is necessary for data purposes, a m2m field will not suffice)

lets say I have a specific model `B` named `b_model`

```
a_models = Connect.objects.filter(b=b_model)
```

above will be a QuerySet of `Connect` objects. I want a QuerySet of `A` objects. The following will do that:

```
a_models = [obj.a for obj in Connect.objects.filter(b=b_model)]
```

but that will evaluate the QuerySet and create a list. **I want to make a QuerySet that has not been evaluated and is of `A` objects. How can I accomplish this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want A objects, start from A.

```
a_objs = A.objects.filter(connect__b=b_model)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just got back into django after a year and forgot I could do that. I'll accept when I am allowed

Answer (score 0):

On `A` or `B` you can define a `ManyToManyField` to the other model (via `Connect`) using the following code

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...
    b_models= models.ManyToManyField(B, through='Connect', through_fields=('a', 'b'), related_name='a_models')
```

Now you can traverse both ways using

```
a_model.b_models  # queryset of Bs
```

And

```
b_model.a_models  # queryset of As
```

And you won't have to query the `Connect` model directly.